# Sorting algorithm implementation

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, quicksort, mergesort

First time poster, sorry if I break any etiquette. 
I'm studying for my Data structures and algorithms midterm and I have a practice problem I don't really understand.

Suppose you are given a sorted list of N elements 
followed by f(N) randomly-order elements.

How would you sort the entire list if f(N) = O(1)?

How would you sort the entire list if 
f(N) = O(log N)?

We have gone over lots of sorting algorithms but the exam focuses on Insertion, Quick and Merge Sort. I don't really understand what it means by if F(N) = O(log N). Is that using Big oh notation to say that the most amount of random elements on the end would be either a constant or log(N) in each respect case.

Thanks for any insight.

Edited: Fixed my obvious mistake in terms of Big Oh notation, not sure where to go from here though.

Comment: O(1) is not the same as 1. It's any fixed number of elements. Similar for O(logN).

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik That much should have been obvious to me, I just don't understand how big Oh notation fits into this problem.

Comment: Well, it fits right there where you have to understand how many unsorted elements you have. You have either O(1) or O(logN) such elements.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I see now, I guess I was making a mistake in not considering algorithm design but more a weird specific case. So assuming you knew that you had a fixed number of elements at the end of a sorted list, you would want to design a sort that would take advantage of this presorted data, my thought would be mergesort.

Comment: I'm pretty sure f(N) means the function of finding an element. So you should understand how Merge/Quick sort work and then apply their limitations/benefits in regards to look up requirements - this will determine which fits each case.

Comment: The problem statement sounds bogus to me. The only important thing is the ratio of sorted to unsorted elements. What if your N is 10 and your F(N) = 1,000,000? How does it matter that the function is O(1)? Same story for O(logN).

Comment: @CharlesGoodwin The list contains "f(N) randomly-ordered elements."

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik That's why I'm confused, I was trying to design the sort based on whether  I would have a small, roughly equal, or large amount of unsorted data relative to my sorted partition, but the way the question is written doesn't seem to provide any insight into that.

Comment: The way I see it, you could sort just the random portion of the list (using QuickSort or MergeSort) and then execute a single MergeSort step where you combine the sorted with the unsorted part.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik That seems to be the most logical solution, I guess the context confused me and I didn't know if I was missing something. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first example you are given a problem, where a constant number of non-ordered elements follow the sorted sequence. In essence this means that you may implement an algorithm to insert a single non-ordered element and then repeat it several times. The overall complexity of inserting all f(N) = O(1) elements will be the same. One of the algorithms you mention is best to perform this operation.

In the second case you have number of elements to be inserted in the order of log(n). In this case you can not ignore this number as it is dependent on the input size. Thus you need to think of a smarter way to merge it with the remaining part that is already sorted. (TIP: maybe the operation you need to perform will help you choose an algorithm?)

Comment: So Merge sort is probably what you are hinting at for the first example since the problem is literally merging.  For the second case it's obvious that the unsorted portion will be small in regards to N, but I don't know where that leaves the design.'

Comment: Actually first one is more like insert while second is merge